# Is it possible to retrieve records from a database using an either all records or matching id method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Basically I want to know if it is possible using as an example, Entity Framework, to retrieve all records from the DB table when the provided id doesn't match any of the id's in the table, but if there are id's that match then only retrieve those records.

It is possible to do obviously if you use an if statement or a ?: expression, as an example below.

```
var dbDocuments = new List<tblSalesQuoteDocument>();

    if (id < 0)
        dbDocuments = dbContext.tblSalesQuoteDocuments.ToList();
    else
        dbDocuments = dbContext.tblSalesQuoteDocuments.Where(x => x.HeaderId == id).ToList();
```

But I find this pretty ugly because if you want all records your URL is basically Documents/Index/-1 or any value less than 0.

Is there a better way?

Why I want one ActionResult is because I do a lot of filtering and code specific stuff in it. I could use two methods, 1 for all records, and another for specific records.

So should I do it as my question above or just use two methods and abstract all my filtering and other code away in Helper Methods to reduce code duplication?

Comment: Which is it, do you want all of the records when the ID doesn't match any existing records, or when the ID is less than 0? These are not the same thing.

Comment: Apologies if it isn't worded well. mybirthname's comment below makes sense in that when no parameter is passed, and id is null then all records should be retrieved, but if an id is supplied, only the records matching that id should be retrieved. I know it can be done using below commented examples with if's and so on, but can it be done without using if or ?:

Comment: So you want your code to do conditionally different things without using any conditional logic? Why? Why don't you want to use `if` or `?:`?

Comment: I never said I want to use it that way, or that I won't use conditional logic. I want to know if it is possible. I'm curious to know if it is possible to query the database in such a manner using Linq or Lambda. Simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

You could add your filter expression on demand. Example:

```
ActionResult MyAction(int? id = null)
{
    // ...

    IQueryable<QuoteDocuments> docs = dbContext.tblSalesQuoteDocuments;

    if (id != null)
    {
        docs = docs.Where(x => x.HeaderId == id.Value);
    }

    var list = docs.ToList();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think his problem is that he don't want to write Documents/Index/-1 url part.

Comment: @mybirthname oh, ok. That would also make sense. I update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 docs =  dbContext.tblSalesQuoteDocuments.Any(x => x.HeaderId == id)?  dbContext.tblSalesQuoteDocuments.Where(x => x.HeaderId == id) :  dbContext.tblSalesQuoteDocuments.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rather use

```
if(dbContext.tblSalesQuoteDocuments.Any(x => x.HeaderId == id)){
...
}
```